# CSS margin-top makes div go out of parent's height

Tags: html, css

I have problem setting layout because one of my child divs makes goes out of it's parent div.

I have: header with 10% height, container with height 90%, and inside one 'div1' with height set to 90% and margin-top set to 10%. If I remove margin-top everything is ok, if not it goes out of parent size creating scrolls etc. (I want div1 height set, I dont need height set to auto etc.)

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5q9vh93n/

### HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="div1">1</div>
        <div id="div2">2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

### CSS:

```
body, html
{
    color: white;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
#header
{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 10%;
}
#container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: gray;
}
#div1 {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 15.67%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    height: 90%;
}
#div2 {
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    width: 43.17%;
    margin-right: 3.6%;
}
```

Comment: When you use percents to apply the margin of an element, the browsers determine the actual size of the margin by multiply the percent against the width of the parent node. It is not based on either the height or width of the element that the margin is applied to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Transform here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5q9vh93n/1/)

```
#div1 {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  width: 15.67%;
  transform: translateY(10%);
  margin-left: 1.5%;
  height: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Nice one. Simple and sweet :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `position: absolute;` and change `margin-top` to `top` , `margin-left` to `left`. So css of #div as follow:

```
#div1 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 15.67%;
    top: 10%;
    left: 1.5%;
    height: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was really surprised when I've discovered this, but vertical padding and margin are relative to the parent's width, not height.

To solve your problem, you can use the `top` property instead, which is relative to the parent's height, as you expect.

So, just change your code to this, and it'll work.

```
#div1 {
    top: 10%;
    position: relative;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5q9vh93n/2/

Hope it helps!